# Display the body of webpage in Xamarin forms

Tags: xamarin.forms

I want to display the body of a webpage like Microsoft use with "Microsoft News". If I use webview, it will show the whole webpage. So, Is there another control or another way ?
Microsot News:
[image: a part of webpage displayed]

My App with webview:
[image: the whole webpage displayed]

Answer (score 0):

You can inject javascript in the LoadUrl method.

For example

```
mWebView.loadUrl("javascript:(function() { " +
        "var head = document.getElementsByClassName('header')[0].style.display='none'; " +
        "})()");
```

From the [official documentation](https://developer.xamarin.com/api/member/Android.Webkit.WebView.LoadUrl/p/System.String/).

Comment: Hi Bruno, Can you explain more?

Comment: When you are loading a url, you can pass javascript to be executed, for example to hide the header section. That's what the example is all about.

Comment: I'm using xamarin forms, so my webview have not loadurl. You mean is xamarin.android ?

Comment: Yes, you need a custom renderer, such as described here https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/xamarin-forms/app-fundamentals/custom-renderer/hybridwebview